# Making powershell's ParameterSet work with FileInfo and FileInfo[]

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have the following code:

```
Function SCCE {
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$True, ValueFromPipeLine=$True,ParameterSetName="Files")]
    [System.IO.FileInfo[]]$sourceFiles,
    [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$True, ValueFromPipeLine=$True, ParameterSetName='File')]
    [System.IO.FileInfo]$sourceFile
)
PROCESS {
    Write-Host $PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName
}
}
```

I wish to make this work for the types specified, and as far as I can tell, it doesn't, even when the types are exact.

For example:

```
$file = (ls)[0]
$file.getType() #FileInfo
SCCE $file
```

> SCCE : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named
>   parameters. At line:1 char:1
>   + SCCE $file
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [SCCE], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,SCCE

Commenting out the sourceFiles parameter seems to file the problem, but I don't understand why this is ambiguous. It is a perfect match for the second parameter.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you tried to specify default parameter set?

Comment: @PetSerAl H'm, no. That seemed to work though. Is there a way to solve the core issue though (that Powershell is looking for an approximate match in the presence of an exact one)?

Comment: As I never see documentation describing exact behavior of parameter set resolution for PowerShell, specifying default parameter set is the best thing I can offer.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you've got them both set to `Mandatory=$True`, or why you even have a set for each type. Just use an array, if there's only one file to pass it'll just be an array of length 1.

```
Function SCCE {
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$True,ValueFromPipeLine=$True,ParameterSetName="Files")]
    [System.IO.FileInfo[]]$sourceFiles
)
  PROCESS {
    Write-Host $PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName
  }
}
```

Then you can call like:

```
> SCCE (gci . -file)
Files
> SCCE (gci . -file)[0]
Files
```

Comment: This is a toy example to illustrate the problem. In reality, those two cases are handled differently. Is there a way to prevent the implicit cast to array in the presence of an exact match?

Comment: Why would you want to? Presumably if you have an array you iterate over it in some way? Why not just do that even if there's only one element to iterate over?

Comment: I guess I could do that, but it seems odd that Powershell does not go for the exact match if its available. The other thing is that the base case is actually the one file (if it is given an array of files, it concatenates them in a particular way, then passes it off to the one file case)

Comment: @soandos [You can](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3941454/696808).  You just can't do that *and* make all the parameters mandatory.  Mandatory means *always* mandatory, regardless of positional overloads.