# Powershell does not use TLS 1.2 in some scripts

Tags: powershell, ssl

I use a powershell script to check the expiration date of certificates.
To to so, I use the code below. The script used to work perfectly for a long time but now fails.
When checking with Wireshark I saw, that the "client hello" is using TLS1.0.

So this statement

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

has either never been working or is ignored now.
There are no registry keys in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols regarding TLS, only SSL3 is disabled.

On the same machine, a different script doing REST calls, is working perfectly with TLS1.2, regardless if the statement above is in the code or not.
Appreciate any ideas because all searches just point out to this:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

and this is unfortunately not working.

BR
Burn

```
# use TLS 1.2
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

$date= Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMdd"
$infile=type myInfile.txt
$outfile = $date+"-myoutFile.txt"

foreach ($url in $infile) 
{
    $Certificate = ""
    $output =""   
    $TcpClient = New-Object Net.Sockets.TcpClient
    $TcpClient.Connect($url, 443)
    $SslStream = New-Object Net.Security.SslStream $TcpClient.GetStream()
    $SslStream.SslProtocol 
    $SslStream.ReadTimeout = 1500
    $SslStream.WriteTimeout = 1500
    try
    {
        #$url
        $SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient($url)
        $Certificate = $SslStream.RemoteCertificate
        if ($Certificate -isnot [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2]) 
        { 
            $Certificate = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 -ArgumentList $Certificate 
        }
        $output = $url.ToString() + ";" + $Certificate.Subject  +";"+ $Certificate.NotBefore.ToShortDateString() + ";" + $Certificate.NotAfter.ToShortDateString() +";"+ $Certificate.Issuer
        $output
        Out-File -nonewline -append -filepath $outfile -InputObject $output
        echo "" >> $outfile
    } 
    catch
    {    
        $output = $url +";"+"Failed"
        $output
        Out-File -nonewline -append -filepath $outfile -InputObject $output
        echo "" >> $outfile
    }
    $TcpClient.Dispose()
    $SslStream.Dispose()
}
```

Comment: The AuthenticateAsClient method in the SSLstream class has an overload where you can force the use of a specific tls version

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but as far as I understand this article you cannot overload in powershell: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940722/function-overloading-in-powershell

Comment: ..and if you could, I don't see a constructor in the documentation to do so: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.net.security.sslstream?view=netcore-3.1#constructors

Comment: You can use .NET method overloads in Powershell (I use them all the time). In your code sample you have an instance of an sslstream in the $sslstream variable. Just type in $sslstream.AuthenticateAsClient (without the parenthesis) to see the overloads of the method. Link to the method: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.sslstream.authenticateasclient?view=netcore-3.1#System_Net_Security_SslStream_AuthenticateAsClient_System_String_System_Security_Cryptography_X509Certificates_X509CertificateCollection_System_Security_Authentication_SslProtocols_System_Boolean_

Comment: Hm... okay. I had a different (but maybe wrong understanding of overloading). I've tried your suggestion but struggle in constructing a new instance. Tried these ways: 
$SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient($url, System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols)
$SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient($url, enabledSslProtocols) unfortunately w/o success. :(